# General Proof on Potential Method and Amortized Analysis

Tags: data-structures, amortized-analysis, splay-trees

Let $T$ be an arbitrary data structure for a dynamic set. For every state T of $T$, let  $d_t \in \mathbb{N}$. Observe two Operations $O_1, O_2$ on $T$ whose runtimes are proportional to $d_t$ and $O_1$ does not change the structure of $T$. Let $f\colon \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N} $. Suppose there exists a potential $\phi$ for which $O_2$ has an amortised complexity in $O(f(|T|))$. Show that there exists a potential $\phi'$ for which $O_1$ and $O_2$ together have an amortised complexity in $O(f(|T|))$.

I'm not sure how one would go about proving this Statement maybe because of the general nature or the formalism of the question but I'm not getting anywhere. I would be very grateful for any hints/explanations on how to approach this question.

Edit:
What I think might be the Solution:

We know the amortized complexity of $O_2$ is given by
$A_2=x_2*d_T + \phi(T´) - \phi(T)$

To show that $A_{1+2} \in O(f(|T|))$ we need to define a potential $\phi´$ such that
$A_{1+2} = x_1*d_t + x_2 *d_T + \phi´(T´) - \phi´(T) = c*(x_2*d_T + \phi(T´) - \phi(T))$
for some constant $c$.

Which should work for $\phi´(T) = \frac{x_1 +x_2}{x_2}*\phi(T)$

Comment: What constraint are you given on $O_1$? If there isnt a constraint, then $O_1$ can by itself take time much larger than $O(f(|T|))$

Comment: Only that $O_1$ runtime is proportional to $d_t$, and that it does not change the Structure of $T$. As a bit of context we are doing some stuff on Splay Trees and if I´m correct one can think of $O1$ as being a standard BST Search Operation and $O_2$ as the Splay operation (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree).

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?  This may help us understand exactly what is being asked.

Comment: What is $|T|$?  Does it relate to $d_t$?

Comment: It is the number of Elements in $T$ for example for a Binary Search Tree the number of Nodes. This is a question from my Computer Oriented Mathematics Class, using the Proof of the above statement we are supposed to show that searching for an element in a Splay Tree, with standard BST Search + Splaying at the end, has an amortized complexity in $O(log(n))$ where n is the number of Nodes in the Tree. (Using a suitable potential).

Comment: I think normally one would need to show that although a Splay Tree is not Balanced, the amortized complexity of BST Search behaves as if the Tree where Balanced (Average Height in $O(log(n))$ and we have already proven (in Lectures) that the Splay Function has amortized complexity in $O(log(n))$ so together they would have the same amortized complexity. But in this case we are supposed to do the Abstract Proof and then derive the same result from that.

Comment: If I understand your question and your comment, $O_1$ is BST Search and $O_2$ is splaying. If this is correct then you can simply charge $O_2$ twice with the same amortized cost. This seems straightforward, so maybe I am missing something about the question?

Comment: I assumed that $O_1$ is BST search since this operation does not change the structure while splaying does change the structure of the tree, hence it's $O_2$. And both operations when done one after the other on the same access path in the tree will have the same worst-case cost. This will lead to the answer I have above.

Comment: I edited my question with what I think is the answer, sorry if my comments were vague i was trying to contextualize the question I had originally posted.